# Remove Duplicate Column Rows from Stored Procedure Result and concatenate other column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have this code for a stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT teams.name,
            IFNULL(users.email,'N/A') as email,
            IFNULL(users.name,'N/A') as user_name,
            IFNULL(team_user.role,'N/A') as role
    FROM teams
        LEFT JOIN team_user ON teams.id=team_user.team_id
        LEFT JOIN users ON team_user.user_id=users.id
    WHERE role is NULL
    OR role='admin';
END
```

I would like to display the result of the stored procedure in a table. The following is an example of the table that it displays:

| Team Name | User Name |
| --- | --- |
| Team1 | AdminUser1ForTeam1 |
| Team1 | AdminUser2ForTeam1 |
| Team 2 | AdminUser1ForTeam1 |
| Team3 | AdminUser1ForTeam3 |
| Team3 | AdminUser2ForTeam3 |

The problem with this table is that if a team has more than 1 admin, the team name will be repeated in two separate rows. The following is the result I want to achieve:

| Team Name | User Name |
| --- | --- |
| Team1 | AdminUser1ForTeam1, AdminUser2ForTeam1 |
| Team 2 | AdminUser1ForTeam1 |
| Team3 | AdminUser1ForTeam3, AdminUser2ForTeam3 |

I tried using group_concat however that cannot detect when the team name is a duplicate.
I can also use php to try and achieve the result. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation.  I suspect you really want:

```
SELECT t.name,
        COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(u.email), 'N/A') as email,
        COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(u.name), 'N/A') as user_name,
        COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(tu.role), 'N/A') as role
FROM teams t LEFT JOIN
     team_user tu
     ON t.id = tu.team_id AND tu.role = 'admin' LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON tu.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY t.name
```